# Как выровнять Div по вертикали?

Tags: html, css

html

```
        <div id="tovar">
            <div class="cont">
                <div id="name">
                <a href="#"> Длинны текст, очень дилнный, которые не помещается в div name и я его переношу
                </div>

                <div id="kol" align="center">
                </div>

                <div id="sum" align="center"> 
                </div>

                <div id="del" align="center"> 
                </div>
        </div>
```

css

```
#name {
text-decoration: none;
width:50%;
display:inline-block;
height: 100%;
border: solid 1px black;
}

#name а { 
white-space: initial;
}


#kol {
white-space:nowrap;
width:12%;
display:inline-block;
border: solid 1px red;
height: 100px;
}

#sum {
white-space:nowrap;
width:23%;
display:inline-block;
}

#del {
white-space:nowrap;
width:10%;
display:inline-block;
}

.cont{
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
}

#name а { //перенос длинной ссылки
white-space: initial;
}
```

И ситуация следующая. Если слово не переносится в блоке name, то справолежащие блоки остаются на месте и всё хорошо, а если переносится, то они едут вниз.
[image: скрин1]

Comment: Для этих блоков установить vertical-align: top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У блоков с `display: inline-block;` по-умолчанию `vertical-align: baseline;`,

чтобы изменить выравнивание, задайте     `vertical-align: top;` или     `vertical-align: middle;` (если нужно будет по середине выравнивать).

```css
#name {
  text-decoration: none;
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

#name а { 
  white-space: initial;
}


#kol {
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:12%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 100px;
}

#sum {
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:23%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#del {
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:10%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cont{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}

#name а { //перенос длинной ссылки
  white-space: initial;
}
```

```html
<div id="tovar">
  <div class="cont">
    <div id="name">
      <a href="#"> Длинны текст, очень дилнный, которые не помещается в div name и я его переношу</a>
    </div>

    <div id="kol" align="center"> </div>

    <div id="sum" align="center"> </div>

    <div id="del" align="center"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```